# How to represent connection string in app.config file

Tags: sql-server

I have an app.config file which is having an entry like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
        <add key="ServerFilePath" value="file://c:\sybase\ini\sql.ini?"/>
  </appSettings>
```

As mentioned in the above code, the setting is for Sybase database. Now, i need to change this file for the SQL Server 2008R2 and we don't use any kind of ini file in sql server.

Please suggest me how to represent connection string for Sql Server.

Comment: Your app.config looks like what.. ? *searches*...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

More [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Answer (score 0):

There's [a very handy reference](http://www.connectionstrings.com) for this sort of thing online.  SQL Server connection strings generally look like these:

- `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
  Password=myPassword;`
- `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;`
- `Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=c:\asd\qwe\mydbfile.mdf;Database=dbname;
  Trusted_Connection=Yes;`

And so on, depending on the options for connection.